# Symplectic form on a Kähler manifold can be not real analytic?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, real-analytic-structures

Let $M$ be a Kähler manifold. The complex structure on it naturally gives rise to the real analytic structure. I wonder if there exist Kähler manifolds such that the associated symplectic $2$-form $\omega$ is $C^\infty$-smooth but not real analytic.

Comment: What about a small disk in $\mathbb{C}$ with $\omega = \overline{\partial}\partial \left(\|z\|^2 + \varepsilon e^{-1/|z|}\right)$?

Comment: @BertramArnold Yes, you're right but it should be $e^{-1/|z|^2}$ instead of $e^{-1/|z|}$. Just a misprint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is positive for any Kähler  manifold.

Consider first surfaces. Take a compact Riemann surface $\Sigma$, then any symplectic form on it is associated to a Kähler form, so the answer is yes, since there are plenty of non-analytic $2$-forms.

More generally, for any Kähler manifold $M$ take any  Kähler form $\omega$ and let $\omega_1$ be a closed $(1,1)$-form supported in a ball $B\subset M$. Then $\omega+\varepsilon \omega_1$ is Kähler for small $\varepsilon$, but not analytic.

Comment: Why doesn't the second argument work for a Riemann surface?

Comment: Dear Deane, I have not said that it doesn't work for surfaces, it does.

Answer (score 5):

Not quite an answer, but something related to it.

There is this [paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2000-128-10/S0002-9939-00-05713-0/home.html) where the authors prove, that for every symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$ there is an analytical manifold $M^a$ and an analytical symplectic form $\omega^a$ such that $(M,\omega)$ and $(M^a,\omega^a)$ are symplectomorphic.

**Edit:** The manifold $(M^a,\omega^a)$ is unique up to symplectomorphisms.